# Bipedalwalker from openai gym solving using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, openai-gym

i am trying to solve the Bipedalwalker from openai. The Problem is that i always get the error:
The shape of the output should be 4 values between -1 and 1(like: [ 0.45099565 -0.7659952  -0.01972992  0.62626314])
So i defined the model like this:

```
def build_model(states, actions):
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, states)))
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
return model
```

states = 24 and actions=4.
When i try to train the model i get the error: IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
I think its because the output of the model is greater then 1 or less then -1.
Is there a way to fix this and force the output to be between -1 and 1 for all 4 outputs?

My whole code is:

```
import gym
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v3")
states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.shape[0]

print(actions)
print(env.action_space.sample())


def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, states)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model


model = build_model(states, actions)
print(model.summary())


def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy,
                   nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn


dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)

_ = dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=15, visualize=True)

dqn.save_weights('dqn_weights.h5f', overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your last layer output to fit -1..1 range by simply replacing its activation function from `linear` to `tanh`.

However, `DQNAgent` is to be used with [discrete action space](https://keras-rl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/agents/overview/) and BipedalWalker has continuous action space.